# How to add permission entry with condition?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, permissions, ntfs

For a Windows folder, Advanced security settings can be entered. In Windows 2016 there is frame "Add a condition to limit access. The principal will be granted the specified permissions only if conditions are met."

Items (= security groups) can be added and is basically selecting one or more AD security groups (when Dynamic Access Control (DAC) is not further installed.

The question is, how can we program in C# (or powershell) adding (and removing) such a condition with two AD security groups.

[image: Add-Condition-With-Two-AD-Groups]

Answer (score 4):

A pretty old question, but just in case somebody still googles for an answer. The access rule in the screenshot seems to be kind of extension to regular ACL.

The only way to modify it I found is through the SDDL.

1. Get ACL Object: `$acl = Get-Acl -Path $FolderPath`
2. Get current SDDL string: `$acl.Sddl`
3. Expand an existing entry with the conditional rule like this (Note `X`, `0x1301bf` and `;(Member_of_any {SID(S-1-5-21-XXX-XXX-XXX-1619)})` parts).

```
(A;OICI;FA;;;S-1-5-21-XXX-XXX-XXX-1113)
```

```
(XA;OICI;0x1301bf;;;S-1-5-21-XXX-XXX-XXX-1113;(Member_of_any {SID(S-1-5-21-XXX-XXX-XXX-1619)}))
```

More examples can be learned by examining different SDDLs from GUI-made objects.

4. Modify $acl object: `$acl.SetSecurityDescriptorSddlForm($NewSddl)`
5. Re-apply it to the folder: `Set-Acl -Path $FolderPath -AclObject $acl`